# Draw a rectangle on an image in gui on mouse hover

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

This question has two parts.
First I want to draw a rectangle on an image in gui only when the mouse hovers on the image. Secondly,  if the user clicks the image, clicking should execute a set of statements or a function. Right now, I can only draw the rectangle on the image in following manner,

```
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% maxSliderValue = get(handles.slider1, 'Max')
% minSliderValue = get(handles.slider1, 'Min')
% theRange = maxSliderValue - minSliderValue
% steps = [1/theRange, 10/theRange]
% set(handles.slider1, 'SliderStep', steps);

set(handles.slider1, 'BackgroundColor',[1,1,1]);
set(handles.slider2, 'BackgroundColor',[.9,.9,.9]);
set(handles.slider1, 'Value', round(hObject.Value));

axes(handles.axes1)
matlabImage = imread('image.tif');
image(matlabImage)
axis image
axis off

[r,c,~]=size(Image);
rectangle('Position', [-2,-2,c+4,r+4],'EdgeColor','r');
```

This is under slider control, later when I will change the slider the image in the figure will change but I can do this. Its not a problem.
For example this function should be executed when user clicks the image

```
call_when_user_clicked_image();
```

Thank you for your support.

Note: Mouse hovers means, mouse on image, draw rectangle on image, mouse not on image no rectangle.

[image]

Comment: How will the user control the size of the rectangle without clicking? In any case, if you have the image processing toolbox, take a look at [`drawrectangle`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/drawrectangle.html) (or `imrect` if version < R2018b).

Comment: rectangle is controlled by the image size. I updated the question/code. Actually, I am unable to find the mouse positions i.e. when mouse hovers and when not. I an now use `WindowButtonMotionFcn`